# Focusing On An Input Box Quickly Will Delete The First Two Characters Typed!

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome, text-input

If I focus on a user-input box, select what's in it, press delete, and start typing, the first two characters I type will get selected and deleted.

Let's say this is an input box:

> Input Content

I put my cursor there:

> Input Content |

I select:

> |`Input Content`

I delete:

> |

I type:

> `a`|
>
> `b`|
>
> c |
>
> cd |
>
> cde |

When I type in an input box that I have selected in, the first two characters are selected and deleted.

Comment: Is this universal in your system, or particular to a certain application?  If universal, you may notice in the Keyboard settings under replace text certain combinations are causing the issue.  Just a little more info regarding the applications it occurs in or other circumstances would help in offering a solution.  Cheers!

Comment: Universal to system.

Comment: One more question, do you have a 3rd party auto-enter application like **Text Expander** installed?

Comment: No, never heard of that.

Comment: I have seen this bug too. It's too rare for me to figure out its cause though...

Comment: Not clear to me, what Input box, does it happen in plain TextEdit, or in Notes, or only in predefined boxes

Comment: I mean input boxes like in online forms and such.

Comment: Thank you, you know those boxes are preset how much you can type in them. Is it Adobe form or web based (Java). Also I guess the "Input content" is grayed out.

Comment: No it's just that selecting a text box on Mac will make the following 2 characters I type after that get selected as well.

Comment: I have not encountered that, on Firefox or Chrome, I do not use Safari.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer by myself.

Input boxes in web forms tend to lag a little, and so does my selection. If I select all the text in the input box, dragging my cursor from the end to the beginning, the selected area will lag behind half a second.

That lag is what causes the problem. When I start typing afterwards, the selection is still active, causing it to replace one or two characters if I type too fast.